# pregunta sobre PtrToStructure y lectura de procesos

Tags: c#, windows

Tengo un problema en la lectura de algunos procesos, les explico...

Empiezo normal tomando el procesos a seguir...

```
IntPtr OpenProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PAGE_READONLY, false, id_handle);
```

Así puedo leer el proceso sin problema e intento leer después

```
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER

IMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader;

dosHeader = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER)Marshal.PtrToStructure(mapVw, typeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER));
```

Lo hago de está manera, pero tengo un problema, hay procesos con los cuales no hay ningún error, pero hay procesos que están protegidos y me sale el siguiente error.

```
System.AccessViolationException
 
  Mensaje = Intento de leer o escribir en la memoria protegida. A menudo, esto indica que hay otra memoria dañada.
  Origen = mscorlib
  Seguimiento de la pila:
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructureHelper(IntPtr ptr, Object structure, Boolean allowValueClasses)

.... etc.
```

Y el debugger me muestra un problema en Marshal.cs

```
StackCrawlMark stackMark = StackCrawlMark.LookForMyCaller;
object obj = runtimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(publicOnly: false, skipCheckThis: false, fillCache: false, ref stackMark);
PtrToStructureHelper(ptr, obj, allowValueClasses: true);

return obj; <---ERROR
```

Donde "return obj" no permite que avance.

Habrá alguna manera de detectar un procesos que no puede ser leído o evitar ese error a la hora de leer la información del proceso, ya sea avisando que ese proceso no tiene permisos de lectura o desbloqueando el proceso?.

Intente con un `try catch` usando `Exception` y `AccessViolationException` pero no funciona, también detectando `IntPtr.Zero` pero tampoco funciona, incluso leyendo si el proceso esta protegido con `virtualqueryex`, pero ya no me deja leer ningún proceso, pareciera que todos tienen una sección protegida y lo único que busco es mostrar en labels la información del Stub.

¿Alguna idea que me pueda ayudar?

Comment: Intentaste con un `try/catch` pero con un `Exception` generico?